# Ckfinder 500 internal server error in server

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor5, ckfinder

Ckeditor showing an error during image upload by ckfinder in the server but localhost ckfinder is ok. But in the server during image upload showing 500 internal server error. Please give me help to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour]  and read the information guides in the help center [help]. Users are much more likely to help if you (1) show some research effort on your own (Google and StackOverflow searches), (2) learn what are appropriate questions for this forum, (3) show your images and (4) provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to your specific problem.

Comment: this is ckfinder issue, there is no need to share code. If you know any clue answer please.

Comment: It need not be code alone, it can be debug logs too. An internal server error can come for many reasons. Any details around that should help the team.  https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-php/debugging.html

Comment: Yes solved this. During file upload via ftp some files missing from vendor/ckfinder. That's why faces problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes solved this. During file upload via ftp some files missing from vendor/ckfinder. That's why faces problem. So always check file all uploaded properly or not. Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by updating the php version of my server.